# How to create fab over cardview layout in android? How to avoid fab behind cardview in android?

Tags: android, xml

> I would like to create a layout for the Floating Action Button and CardView. The problem is that the Floating Action Button is hide (behind) of the cardview, I tried with the RelativeLayout but not the fab on the CardView, I need some advice.[My Output looks like here, but i need fab on cardview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLCa6.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

> Card1

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/card1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="130dp"
android:layout_margin="6dp"
app:cardElevation="8dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
app:contentPadding="15dp">
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Card 1"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

> Card2

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/card2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="130dp"
android:layout_margin="6dp"
app:cardElevation="8dp"
android:layout_below="@id/card1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
app:contentPadding="15dp">
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Card 2"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

> Card3

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/card3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="130dp"
android:layout_below="@id/card2"
android:layout_margin="6dp"
app:cardElevation="8dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
app:contentPadding="15dp">
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Card 3"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

> Floating Action Button with sub items here

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
android:id="@+id/menu"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true"
app:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
fab:menu_backgroundColor="#ccffffff"
fab:menu_fab_label="Options"
app:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
android:elevation="2dp"
```

> Sub Item1

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/id_share"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/share"
android:padding="5dp"
fab:fab_size="mini"
fab:fab_label="Share"
app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"/
```

> Sub Item2

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/id_copy"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/share"
android:padding="5dp"
fab:fab_size="mini"
fab:fab_label="Copy"
app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"/>
</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Coordinator** **Layout** instead of **Relative Layout** and set **layout_gravity** for fab **bottom|end**

Comment: unfortunately it does not work , While am trying to Coordinator layout instead of RelativeLayout. the FAB is still positioned behind the card.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the elevations?
If the card elevation is bigger than the fab's elevation, it will cover it.

(Just an advise, but try not to use discontinued libraries.)

Comment: It works when half of contents fill of intents. But,the position of fab completely hide more cards in intent.

Comment: Did you change the elevation of the Fab container too? Does it work with plain Fab? I mean not a custom fap, the one from the support library.